# Using pgf-pie to draw pie charts without labels on the slices, but still able to label the individual slices

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I am trying to use a pie chart to represent, well, a pie. I want to label the chart as follows:
[image]

but I want the percentages to not appear on the slices. I added /tikz/nodes={text opacity=0,overlay} to my code to yield the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[rotate=90, explode=0.05, radius=1.5, /tikz/nodes={text opacity=0,overlay}]{33.33/Lizzie's Leftovers, 66.66/Amount Lizzie ate};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

which gets rid of the percentages, but also the slice labels. Is there a way to just remove the percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are!
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[fill=cyan] 
(0,0)--(90:2) arc(90:-150:2)--cycle
(-30:2.2) node[right]{Amount Lazzie ate};

\draw[fill=blue!50,shift={(150:1mm)}] 
(0,0)--(90:2) arc(90:210:2)--cycle
(150:2.2) node[left]{Lazzie's Leftovers};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: `pgf-pie` has changed some internals. The following MWE works for the version currently on Github (https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie, dated December 26th 2020).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{showpct}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@slice}%
{\pgfpie@scalefont{#3}\pgfpie@numbertext{#3}}%
{\iftoggle{showpct}{\pgfpie@scalefont{#3}\pgfpie@numbertext{#3}}{}}%
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\togglefalse{showpct}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[rotate=90, explode=0.05, radius=1.5]{33.33/Lizzie's Leftovers, 66.66/Amount Lizzie ate};
\end{tikzpicture}

\toggletrue{showpct}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[rotate=90, explode=0.05, radius=1.5]{33.33/Lizzie's Leftovers, 66.66/Amount Lizzie ate};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Original answer: You can modify the code of `pgf-pie` to switch off the percentage printing. The modification can be done using the `etoolbox` package, which provides a command `\patchcmd`. This command has five arguments: the command that you want to modify, the piece of code within this command that will be affected, the replacement commands that will be inserted instead of the piece of code indicated in the second argument, and two arguments specifying what should be done if the modification succeeds or fails, respectively. Those final two commands are useful for debugging, but are generally left empty once the code is working.

The code responsible for drawing the percentages is on line 59 and 60 of `pgf-pie.sty`. You can modify the second line to switch off the printing. In the MWE below a toggle (called `showpct`) is used, this is a boolean provided by `etoolbox` which can be used to execute different code based on whether the toggle is true or false. Here, if the `showpct` toggle is true, then the original code will be executed, otherwise no code will be executed (and therefore the percentage will not be printed).

Because the `\pgfpie@slice` command that is modified contains an `@` symbol, the patching needs to be surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{showpct}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@slice}%
{\scalefont{#3}\beforenumber#3\afternumber}%
{\iftoggle{showpct}{\scalefont{#3}\beforenumber#3\afternumber}{}}%
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\togglefalse{showpct}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[rotate=90, explode=0.05, radius=1.5]{33.33/Lizzie's Leftovers, 66.66/Amount Lizzie ate};
\end{tikzpicture}

\toggletrue{showpct}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[rotate=90, explode=0.05, radius=1.5]{33.33/Lizzie's Leftovers, 66.66/Amount Lizzie ate};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]